# How ETX (Estimated Transmissions) is implemented in contikiRPL?

Tags: moving-average, contiki

I am working on creating a modified version of MRHOF for RPL. However, I
have some doubts about the ETX metrics used. i am running an rpl-udp example *(..../contiki-3.0/examples/ipv6/rpl-udp)*.

As per my understanding, the general definition of ETX is following:

`ETX = 1/(df * dr)`

where `df` is the measured probability that a data packet successfully arrives at the recipient and `dr` is the probability that the ACK packet is successfully received.

The implementation of ETX is defined in `neighbor_link_callback(rpl_parent_t *p, int status, int numtx)` *(contiki/core/net/rpl/rpl-mrhof.c)* as below:

`new_etx = ((uint32_t)recorded_etx * ETX_ALPHA +(uint32_t)packet_etx * (ETX_SCALE - ETX_ALPHA)) / ETX_SCALE`

where

```
  recorded_etx = nbr->link_metric 
  packet_etx = MAX_LINK_METRIC * RPL_DAG_MC_ETX_DIVISOR
  nbr->link_metric = RPL_INIT_LINK_METRIC * RPL_DAG_MC_ETX_DIVISOR    (rpl-dag.c)
  RPL_INIT_LINK_METRIC = 2                                            (rpl-conf.h)
  ETX_SCALE = 100
  ETX_ALPHA = 90
  RPL_DAG_MC_ETX_DIVISOR = 256                                        (rpl-private.h)
  MAX_LINK_METRIC = 10
```

Here every time when link layer receives an ACK or time-out event  the function inside this file (neighbor_link_callback) is fired.

I understood the formal definition of ETX, but when i am trying to map the standard ETX formula with contikiRPL's ETX formula then i am facing some trouble in understanding the implementation of ETX in contikiRPL.

How the probability of a data packet successfully arrives at the recipient (`df`) and probability that the ACK packet is successfully received (`dr`) are implemented in ContikiRPL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, `df` and `dr` individually are not known. The algorithm is run on the sender device, which has no means to differentiate between the case when the packet is lost and the case when the ACK is lost. They look exactly the same to it: as the absence of the

The value of `packet_etx` roughly corresponds to `1 / (df * dr)` of the *last packet*. Note that a single packet already may have had multiple retransmissions on the link. The metric is updated only when the packet is successfully ACKed or when the maximal number of retransmissions is exceeded.

Another issue in Contiki is that since its designed for embedded systems, it does not have the memory to keep in track the ETX of many recent packets. Instead, this information is aggregated in single value with the help of [exponentially weighted moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) (EWMA) filter. The `\alpha` paramter of the algorithm is given  as ETX_ALPHA / ETX_SCALE in the code; the scaling is done to avoid the more expensive floating point operations.

The value of `recorded_etx` is the previous value of the ETX, reflecting the ETX calculated from all of the previous packets. The value of `new_etx` is the value of the link's ETX when the previous ETX and the last packet's ETX have been combined with the ETX algorithm.

Comment: For calculation of ETX, contikirpl uses control packets (ICMP:DIS) or data packet ? I have doubt regarding this. kindly, correct me.

Comment: @GULSHANSONI - Both.